# How do I cause an error in MSBuild if a file exists?

Tags: msbuild

We have a process that runs prior to our nightly builds.  If the process fails it generates a text file.  All I need to do is check to see if the file exists, and if it does, cause a failing MSBuild.

I currently have tried the following:

```
<CreateProperty Condition="Exists('C:\Process\Fail.txt')"
      Value="false">
  <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="ProcessTestPassed"/>
</CreateProperty>
<Message Text="Process did not pass" Condition="Exists('C:\Process\Fail.txt')" ContinueOnError="false" />

<ReadLinesFromFile File="C:\Process\Fail.txt"                  Condition="'$(ProcessTestPassed)'=='false'" ContinueOnError="false" >
  <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="FileContents" />
</ReadLinesFromFile>
<Message Text="FileContents: $(FileContents)"  Condition="'$(ProcessTestPassed)'=='false'" ContinueOnError="false" />
```

Which gives a passing build with this output:

```
Task "CreateProperty"
Done executing task "CreateProperty".
Task "Message"
  QAWizardProTestPassed did not pass
Done executing task "Message".
Task "ReadLinesFromFile"
Done executing task "ReadLinesFromFile".
Task "Message"
  FileContents: 
Done executing task "Message".
```

I know the above is probably overkill, but I just need something working!  What am I missing here?

Comment: I think I found an acceptable solution:

    <Error Condition="Exists('C:\Process\Fail.txt')" Text="Process did not pass!" />

Comment: That's actually a good solution.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

As noted by @dprice in his comment, the best solution for this would be:

```
<Error Condition="Exists('C:\Process\Fail.txt')" Text="Process did not pass!" />
```

Comment: The problem about this is where you place the `Error` tag. In my case, I'm getting this error: `Error: The <Error> tag is no longer supported as a child of the <Project> element. Place this tag within a target, and add the name of the target to the "InitialTargets" attribute of the <Project> element`

Comment: It is working under a <Target> like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b08t3s4.aspx. (Msvs 2015)