# Is it possible to make Visual Studio use *only* the HintPath for a given Reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio

let's say have multiple older projects, each of which includes a reference to a given dll, like so:

```
<Reference Include="nunit.framework">
  <HintPath>..\lib\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Now, I have updated to use  nuget and **some** projects use a new refenrece like so:

```
<Reference Include="nunit.framework">
  <HintPath>..\packages\NUnit.2.6.4\lib\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

the older dll in `..\lib\` was removed and I *expected* Visual Studio to fail the build for all projects that I forgot to update. Sadly VS does not... Rather it builds against some obscure dll-version it found *somewhere* on my machine..

Can I make VS (or msbuild for that matter) fail the build, if a given `Reference` does not exist on the `HintPath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer to the title - no. It's a hint path, and VS will always search multiple locations for references. However, you could certainly cause the build to fail if a file doesn't exist - for example as answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757344/how-do-i-cause-an-error-in-msbuild-if-a-file-exists) (although the condition would need to be not exists rather than exists).

It is actually a massive pain - as a developer of Visual Studio extensions I find the behaviour surrounding HintPath resolution causes me regular issues.